# ggplot legend key color and transparency

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency, legend, aesthetics

I'm plotting multiple lines together and they are transparent. However, I do not want the legend color to have any transparency. I attempted the `override.aes` but without success.
This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130943/ggplot-legend-showing-transparency-and-fill-color), but essentially the opposite.

Currently I have this

```
# plot all the lines
plt <- ggplot(dt_plot,aes(x = x, y = mean_change, color = model)) +
        geom_line(aes(group = interaction(model, boot)), alpha = 0.3) +
        xlab('houses/acre') + 
        ylab('change in % prevalance') +
        scale_colour_manual(values=cbbPalette) + 
        theme_few()  + 
        theme(text=element_text(size=10),legend.title = element_blank()) + 
        guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes= list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image: transparent lines and transparent legend colors]

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps `guides(color = ...` rather than `guides(fill = ...`? Otherwise, we need a reproducible example.

Comment: champion - that did it. would you like to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine except for one small issue: you need

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

instead as `geom_line` doesn't have the `fill` aesthetic.